# onChanges not working with component binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a component:

```
@Component('Umbrella', {
    selector: 'attachment-list',
    templateUrl: '/AttachmentListComponent/AttachmentList.html',
    bindings: {
        mediaIds: '<',
    }
})

public $onChanges() {
   console.log(this.mediaIds);
}
```

I use the component in a `CaseFlowComponent`:

Component:

I have a upload method:

```
public upload = (file: File) => {
    if (!file || !this.state.caseHistory) return;

    this.uploadService
        .upload({
            url: this.actionUrl,
            data: { file },
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .then((result: any) => {
            this.state.caseHistory.media.push(result.data);
            this.setMediaIds(result.data.id);
        });
};
```

And a method that pushes the id of the uploaded file to the `mediaIds` array.

```
private setMediaIds(mediaId: Guid) {
    this.mediaIds.push(mediaId);
}
```

Template:

```
<attachment-list 
    media-ids='vm.mediaIds'
></attachment-list>
```

The uploaded file id is added correctly to the `this.mediaIds` array in the `caseFlowComponent` but the `$onChanges` is not called in the `attachment-list` component.

I thought `$onChanges` should work when the component binding is updated.

Comment: Which angular version?

Comment: AngularJS version 1.7.8

Answer (score 0):

`$onChanges` compares references. Your options are:

- always create new array
- add another input to trigger on-changes
- run watch manually

Comment: Aren't the references different? In the CaseFlowComponent the mediaIds array has 25 objects, and the AttachmentListComponent has 24. Hm looks like clearing the mediaIds array before pushing a object in it does trigger the onChanges. Might do something with that then.

Comment: There is one array - it first has 24 items, then 25. If you put ng-repeat -- u will see that item is added, but that does not trigger onChanges since it is still same array.

Comment: Ah, I see. The references are the same, but the content is different.